# Calling a ProgressDialog from a Dialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, dialog, progressdialog

I want to offer a search functionality in my app.
The user can open a search dialog, enter a value, and then click on the ok-button to start search.
As the search operation could take longer i want to show a progress-dialog while the search is being processed.

If the user now pushes the ok-button the search dialog stays on top, but the ProgressDialog is not visible.

```
public ProgressDialog pDialog;

private void performSearch() {
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this); 
    pDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.searchCard));
    pDialog.setMessage (Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.searchingCard)));
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

    // do the search part here …    

}


private void searchCard() {
    final Dialog search = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);  
    search.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    search.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_searchcard);
    final EditText etSearch = (EditText) search.findViewById(R.id.edSearch);
    search.setTitle(getString(R.string.search));
    search.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    Button okButton = (Button) search.findViewById(R.id.ok);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            searchString = etSearch.getText().toString();
            performSearch(); 
            search.dismiss(); 
        }
    });

    Button cancelButton = (Button) search.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            search.dismiss();
        }
    });
    search.show();
    search.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.ic_search_color);
}
```

in a second example (not shown in this code) i also tried to implement an AsyncTask (show a ProgressDialog in the onPreExecute of the AsyncTask) - did not work either.

any ideas what could be wrong?

thanks!
Gerhard

Comment: the ProgressDialog is not shown

Comment: where is your AsyncTask class?

Comment: the Async was just a second approach, this is not shown in the example

Comment: @George: no crashes!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Declare a global variable like this:

```
ProgressDialog progress;
```

Wherever you want to show the progress, paste this code:

```
progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait",
                "Loading..", true);
```

When you are done, simply dismiss it:

```
progress.dismiss();
```

Comment: Mohammad, this has the same effect. during the search operation the search-dialog is shown, but not the progress-dialog

Comment: Try one thing. Replace `progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait",
                "Loading..", true);`
with `progress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please wait",
                "Loading..", true);`

Comment: Mohammad, getActivity() is undefined.